# cannot read property 'blur' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using ref in Material-UI TextField as :-

```
<TextField
 label="Select "
 value={this.state.type}
 inputRef={this.selectCar}
 type="text"
/>
```

Here selectCar is defined in constructor as :-

```
this.selectCar = React.createRef();
```

when doing

```
this.selectCar.current.blur;
```

it is giving error

```
cannot read property 'blur' of undefined?
```

Comment: What does `this.selectCar.current` return? `this.selectCar` ? `this`? Take it step by step. It seems that one of them is `undefined`

Comment: At what point to you call `this.selectedCar.current.blur`? Remember that refs are only created after the component was mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check first that selectCar.current exists before trying to access properties on it?  I belive the current object is only created once the refed element is added to the DOM:

```
selectCar.current && selectCar.current.blur
```